# What is a Drut’syla?

Tags: history, words, yiddish, story-identification

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160319051421/http://www.thelastdrutsyla.co.uk/) was sent to me by a friend, about a woman who is a Drut'syla (dertseyler in Yiddish), or storyteller. The article simply says it's a Jewish tradition, but doesn't place it within Judaism. When / where is this tradition from and what, specifically, does it entail? Which communities practised it? What are the tales about? Who wrote them and in what language? Is there a fixed text or an evolving one over time?

Comment: It sounds from that page like (1) this is a tradition of Jews not of Judaism and (2) you'll get more info when the DVD comes out. Because of (1), this seems to be [off-topic](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473).

Comment: נשים המוזרות בלבנה

Comment: "The drut’syla is a storyteller within the Jewish tradition,[...] However, the tradition was uprooted, and came close to extinction, during the Second World War in the mid-twentieth century."  *Prima facie* it looks like this indeed has to do with Judaism, and certainly more so than with Jews